# Pyinstaller Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources.py2_warn' for Python 3.7

Tags: python, pyinstaller, setuptools

Using Pyinstaller on Python 3.7 with setuptools around ver 45.0.0 produces the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources.py2_warn' [24514] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres

This [discussion](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1963) describes it as being caused by the **setuptools update around 45.0.0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [fixed](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1963) in the 49.1.1 version of setuptools released a week ago on 7/10/2020.  So, upgrading setuptools now fixes the issue.  The previous workaround was to downgrade setuptools.

For Win10:

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```